# Which chat api has a good Search function?

Tags: api, chat, messaging

I am developing a web app that is used for professional service professionals (accountants) to create shared workspaces (portals) for each client. These workspaces need a real-time Slack-like conversation across accountant and client -- and a key requirement is to be able to search the message history. I've looked at PubNub ChatEngine, Twilio, TalkJS, Applozic, Sendbird etc. but can't seem to find even one with this Search capability.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you created your account here, it was suggested you take the [tour] and read the [help] pages in order to familiarize yourself with the site. Please do so, especially [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

With PubNub ChatEngine, you can use JavaScript to get past messages in a particular chat. You can write a few lines of JavaScript to filter the messages that are returned. For your use case, you would filter for your search input.

The documentation for this feature is [here](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/chat-engine/reference/chat?devrel_gh=which-chat-api-has-a-good#search).

```js
chat.search({
    event: 'message',
    sender: ChatEngine.me, // You can filter on a specific sender
    limit: 20,             // You can make a limit for the number of messages to recall and search through
    start: "14375189629170609", // Optional beginning time token of messages to search through
    end: "14375189629999999"
}).on('message', (event) => {
    // Filter messages based on search input
}).on('$.search.finish', () => {
    console.log('we have all our results!')
});
```